# Window Phone 7 and One Drive

Tags: onedrive, 7.x

Is there any way to sever the connection with my old Windows phone (that I gave to a family member) and my OneDrive account? I've downloaded the OneDrive app to my new phone to upload pictures, and now after they upload they are viewable on BOTH phones! I need the Windows Phone to no longer be able to access OneDrive. What about if I "remove this phone" at Windowphone.com.? Will that sever the connection? The hard reset done at AT&T when I gave the phone to a family member did not sever the connection. I even changed the password on my OneDrive account and somehow the Windows phone can still access my OneDrive account (no, I didn't update to the new password on the Windows phon). Help! All the photos I shoot on my new phone are viewable on the old Windows phone.

Comment: Has the family member signed in with a new primary account? (i.e. not yours, and set up store, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Since I recently given my old WP7 device to family note, just a note: While adding Microsoft account and deleting the old one sounds like correct idea, I realised you are not able to delete a Microsoft account which was the device set up with at first boot

The only way to do it, sadly, is factory reset

Comment: I would say its better, since you are giving your phone to someone, you better leave no trace of your personal files/apps.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove the Microsoft Account on the Windows Phone 7 device, and switch it to a different account. Go to Settings -> Email + Accounts -> and 'Add an account'.

Have them enter THEIR Microsoft Account, not yours. After that, select your Microsoft Account and remove it.

Comment: In case the account is primary one, you wont be able to delete it. You'll need to reset the phone.